# Why width transition is jumping

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have problems with setting transitions. Basically everything looks ok and is almost working but I have "jumping" effect: instead of changing width smoothly from 100% to 100px it is jumping 100% -> "min-content" -> 100px.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oth8k35q/27/

Main code parts:

```
<div style="display:inline-flex; width: 400px; border: 1px dotted black;">
  <div id="c1" class="active">
    <div> 1 </div> <div id="d1"> 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="c2">
    <div> 1 </div> <div id="d2"> 1 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#d1, #d2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.active, .active #d1, .active #d2 {
  width: 100%;
}

#d1, #d2 {
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

Comment: Do you need these two ````div```` which contains only the ````1```` and ````2```` as prefixes?

Comment: @michaelT, yes. In the example they contain almost nothing but in real case they have content that should remain visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that your *jump* is caused by the `flex-grow` behavior of your flex-box. To avoid this, you can try to animate the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` property. Works in Chrome, not tested in other browsers.

You pseudo *min-width* can be changed by changing the `width` of the class `container`, e.g.

```
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 125px;
  flex-shrink: 100;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), flex-shrink 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

```js
function toggleClasses(){
    document.getElementById('container-1').classList.toggle('active');
    document.getElementById('container-2').classList.toggle('active');
}

document.getElementById('container-1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(document.getElementById('container-1').classList.contains('active')) return;
    toggleClasses();
});

document.getElementById('container-2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(document.getElementById('container-2').classList.contains('active')) return;
    toggleClasses();
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display:inline-flex; 
  width: 400px; 
  border: 1px dotted black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper .container:nth-child(1){
  background: lightblue;
}
.wrapper .container:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper .container:nth-child(1) div:last-child{
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.33);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper .container:nth-child(2) div:last-child{
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.33);
   cursor: pointer;
}

.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 100;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: flex-grow 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), flex-shrink 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.container.active{
  flex-grow: 100;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.element{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container-1" class="container active">
        <div>1</div>
        <div class="element">Content#1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container-2" class="container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div class="element">Content#2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I still don't really understand why there is a problem with `width` but this was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have added **transition: width 1s;** property in **#c1.active #d1, #c2.active #d2**.

```js
var change = function(selector){
  $(".active").removeClass('active');
   $(selector).addClass('active');
}
$('#d1').click(function(){
  change('#c1');
});

$('#d2').click(function(){
  change('#c2')
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}
#d2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
.active{
  width: 100%;
}
#c1, #c2 {
  display: inline-flex;
}
#c1.active #d1, #c2.active #d2 {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; width: 400px; border: 1px dotted black;">
  <div id="c1" class="active">
    <div>1</div>
    <div id="d1">d1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="c2">
    <div>1</div>
    <div id="d2">d2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Active element is expanding smoothly but inactive one is changing without transition.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this as the 100% width will cause issues with the transition.

```
    .active, .active #d1, .active #d2 {
      width: calc(400px - 100px);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my project I cannot have fixed values like 400px. And there is another problem with this solution: #d1, #d2 should not have 400px - 100px, because there is length of texts also within 400px.